# Turn $(N,1)$ vector into $(N,N)$ lower triangle matrix with elements below diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have an $(N,1)$ vector $A$ I would like to turn into a $(N,N)$ lower triangular matrix $B$ with elements uniquely placed below the diagonal in the following manner:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a1\\a2\\a3\end{bmatrix}$$

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\a1&0&0\\a2&a3&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Is there an operation that can transform $A$ into $B$? Or maybe a way of finding the appropriate matrix $C$ such that $AC=B$?

Comment: I’m a bit puzzled by why you accepted the answer that you did. It doesn’t really show how to construct $B$ from the *vector* $A$. It entails filling in *two* matrices with values taken from $A$ instead of only one and begs the question of their construction.

Comment: What would your transformation be for $N=2$? It is not at all clear to me how the $N=3$ case suggests the general case.

Comment: Yet, the answer you accepted doesn’t do either of the things that you actually asked for in the above question. It relates a diagonal matrix, not a vector, to $B$. There’s still a step missing in my mind—the “matrix operation” that turns a vector into a diagonal matrix. However, it’s your question, so it’s certainly your call as to what answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just
$$\left [ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ] \left ( \left [ \begin{matrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{matrix} \right ] \left [ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right ] \right ) + \left [ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right ] \left ( \left ( \left [ \begin{matrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{matrix} \right ] \left [ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right ] \right ) \left [ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right ] \right )
 = \left [ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ a_1 & 0 & 0 \\ a_2 & a_3 & 0 \end{matrix} \right ]$$

I.e. Let $$A = \left [ \begin{matrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
$$B = \left [ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
$$C_1 = \left [ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
$$C_2 = \left [ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
$$C_3 = \left [ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
so that
$$\left [ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ a_1 & 0 & 0 \\ a_2 & a_3 & 0 \end{matrix} \right ] = C_1 ( A B ) + C_2 ( ( A B ) C_3 )$$